# How ssl is usually set up on shared hosting?

Tags: ssl, https

I am quite unclear on how ssl is usually set up on shared hosting. I have account with justhost.com and they provided me with public_html folder and (its sibling) ssl folder. When I create ssl certificates via cPanel it appears in SSL folder. Now, where I should put my html files to be accessible via https:// rather than http? Normal files go into public_html (I figured this out) What about secure bunch?

Also how can I specify that secured folder shouldn't be the ssl folder (if its the one in fact) but rather some other folder I specify? Is it possible at all with shared hosting?

Thank you all for your help, I googled for hours and still am heavily confused as you see.

I'm more interested in how it is done usually with shared hosting, rather than with justhost specifically.

Answer (score 4):

What about you contact them and ask? ;) ServerFault is not a support forum for a SPECIFIC hoster, and you basically ask how THEY work, not how it is normally done.

Answer (score 1):

Most control panels (cPanel and the like) will set each site up with a separate directory for SSL and non-SSL content. Some panels will provide an option to ignore the SSL directory and serve everything from the non-SSL directory, but you have to be extra careful with this approach so as not to expose sensitive information over a non-SSL connection.

Most control panels also don't let you change the directory for SSL content, although the underlying web server is usually flexible enough to allow it (the option is just not presented to you, the end user.)